# Excel Date on Axis

Tags: excel, graph

I'm creating a graph with 5 sorts of data that should have in horizontal axis only 2 values, "10/22" and "11/22" (two dates).

The problem I'm facing is than the Excel creates a strange axis, as you can see:

[image]

How can I, for example, show only horizontal for 09/22-10/22-11/22-12/22?

This is the Axis configuration:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Format the axis and change the minimum and maximum bounds?

Comment: It does not work, or at least i don't know how to do so. The data is in Date format, but on the bounds is in number (type 442019)

Comment: Those numbers represent dates, for example, type 44911 in a cell and format it as a date, you should get today's date displayed in the cell

Comment: To format the axis, select the chart and right-click on the axis

Comment: I've updated the question with the Axis options, i have sincerly no idea on how to change it

Comment: if this is going to remain just two dates, consider a column chart instead.